# Creating array of fields then looping through set in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to simplify how my app builds a query and loops through the results.  Most of the actual code works, except that PHP does not display all of the results fetched from my query.

**PREFACE: example code ahead, do not use in production.**

First I build the query.

```
$arr_fields = array('color', 'number', 'size');
$select_fields = implode(', ', $arr_fields);
$q = "SELECT $select_fields FROM supplychain";
```

Now I execute the query then loop through the result set.
*Pro tip: don't use this code for anything important - it's for demo purposes only.*

```
echo "<table>";
    $res = doQuery($q);

    // create report body
    foreach($res as $r)
    {

         // set values from array of field names
         $row_fields = '';
         foreach ($arr_fields as $f)
         {
            // set current $arr_field value inside a table cell...
            $row_fields.= "<td>$r[$f]</td>";
         }

         // display the row
         echo "<tr>$row_fields</tr>";

    }
echo "</table>";
```

The first database value from `$arr_fields` (`color`) is output as expected, the rest are not.

The assembled query issued at a MySQL console shows values for `color, number and size`.  There aren't any SQL errors generated by the script.

Why is PHP displaying the first field's value but skipping the other two?

Comment: Should work, what is `print_r($res);`?

Comment: `Array
(
    [color] => Red
    [number] => 33145551
    [size] => Large
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$row_fields.= "<td>$r[$f]</td>";
```

to:

```
$row_fields.= "<td>".$r[$f]."</td>";
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately (but looks cleaner, so have a tip).   I discovered the problem while trying this out.   Had spaces in front of the field names in the source array.   Once I removed those, I now see results.

Comment: Ah, a misplaced space. That is annoying to find. Make it a self answer on this question with an example and I will vote it up.

Comment: While this wasn't the problem (because it apparently works with variables in the [ ], but not with constants), I prefer the { } way: `"<td>{$r[$f]}</td>"`
PS: I actually first thought that was the problem, but then figured I'd test it before posting. I was surprised that it does indeed does not fail when used with variables, so I learned something today, so... .thanks for messing up the spaces I guess @acoder ;)

Comment: I've never seen curlies used like that.  I only use them with variable variables `${$value}`

Comment: @acoder http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue turned out to be a space before each of the fieldnames in my array (not shown in the example above).

The field array actually was

```
$arr_fields = array('color', ' number', ' size');
```

Once I removed the spaces, values showed up as usual.  Thanks for Norbert for helping point me in the right direction via additional testing.